# get rpttextbox value

Tags: vb6

I have to generate report using Data report in vb6. I can able to set Data Source from table but the problem is i have a field that the value is **decoded**  or encrypted i want to encode it so the value become readable.

Ill try to get the value of the **rpttextbox** that connected to my DB and i hide this textbox and i set rptlabel that will be hold the encode value of rpttextbox.

In sort rptlabel = encode(rpttextbox)

this is my code

`Sections("Section1").Controls("lblencode").Caption  =  encode(Sections("Section1").Controls("rpttextbox_st").???)`

how do i get the value of the rpttextbox? TY guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do any processing, reformatting, etc. between the data and the DataReport you can write a data source Class or UserControl to be the middleman (DataSourceBehavior property = vbDataSource).

See [Creating a Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241635%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), [Creating Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240786%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), and related topics in the VB6 documentation.